# Adding functionality to directly import certain functions from python sub-packages

Tags: python, package, python-import

Consider a regular python package with following fixed structure

```
myPackage/
├──__init__.py 
├──basic/
│  ├──__init__.py
│  ├──basicOne/
│  │   ├──__init__.py
│  │   ├──f1.py
│  │   └──f2.py
│  ├──a1.py
│  └──a2.py
└──README.md
```

If one wants to import some function `foo()` in `f1.py`, and `roo()` in `a1.py`, then
one can use standard commands

```
from myPackage.basic.basicOne import f1

f1.foo()
```

and

```
from myPackage.basic import a1

a1.roo()
```

Suppose one wants to add a feature where function `foo()` and `roo()` can also be called this way

```
import myPackage as myPack
myPack.foo()
myPack.roo()
```

then what additional code should one write in the package? If such additional code
is written, would it interfere with distributing and installing the top-level package,`myPackage`. Since there are many methods to distribute, lets fix the method to the
one given in [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: What you want is a command line utility with options where your main method depending on the command line calls a different python method.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the most top level `__init__.py` file and import what you need there:

```
from .basic.basicOne.f1 import foo
from .basic.a1 import roo
```